# Calculate Android TranslationY value for different screens and Animation

Tags: c#, android, .net, xamarin, xamarin.android

I have a fragment for more options in my app that I want mostly hidden except for one small rectangle that says "Pull up for more options". This rectangle is parked at the bottom of the screen. When the user pulls it up, it then pops up from the bottom but NOT taking over the full screen, only about 1/3rd of the bottom. Just enough to show some of the options (checkboxes).

I am doing this and have it working by setting the TranslationY setting of the options fragment layout, which is in a FrameLayout container by the way, so that it is at the bottom of the screen and just shows my "Pull up for more options" text.

Then, when they pull up on that, I have some motion events to bring it up to where I want.

Here is the issue, I can get it working just fine on one display using hard coded TranslationY settings. For example, on a Galaxy S2 which has a density of 1.5 (HDPI 240) and a screen of 480x800, these are my hard coded values that work. I had to find them just by playing around with the numbers.

```
int trackOptionsHome = 650; //Parked at bottom of screen.
int trackOptionsExtended = 450; //Extended out where I want it to.
```

Again, with those hard coded values on the S2, it works fine and the way I want. However, if I now try a different device that is STILL HDPI (1.5/240) except the screen size is 480x640 (3.5in), it does not display properly which is to be expected. So then I implemented something like this:

```
float trackOptionsHome = ((dMetrics.HeightPixels / dMetrics.Density) + 120);
float trackOptionsExtended = ((dMetrics.HeightPixels / dMetrics.Density) - 100);
```

This was to try to take into account for different display density and sizes. I was then trying to do math at the end of each to position my fragment where I want it. However, I am getting inconsistent results and the numbers are still arbitrary. I have to find them by playing around.

This raises two questions:
1. How do I make sure I get the results I want on DIFFERENT display densities, which is not even the issue I am having at the moment since I have the same density.
2. How do I scale properly for the different size screens, which appears to be my immediate problem.

For math purposes at the moment (I can adjust as needed after I get an answer) let's say I want 50px of the fragment showing from the bottom when it is in the home position and 300px showing up from the bottom when extended.

What is the correct way to do this?

Thanks!

Mike

Comment: Sorry, forgot to add, dMetrics in the snippets above is this:

Comment: `var dMetrics = Resources.DisplayMetrics;`